# Ajax-free chained drop down menus in Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, forms, dynamic, symfony

So ive got three entities, city, state and country and I want the user to firstly select the country which would narrow down the available states and then when a state in selected it would narrow down the available cites. Fairly straight forward right?

If it doesn't need to be dynamic, you can just use the entity form type then use the `query_builder` to narrow down the results that are returned like so:

```
    ->add('city', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ISFP\Registration\RegisterSchoolAdminBundle\Entity\City',
        'query_builder' => function ($repository) use ($stateId) {
            return $repository
                ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                ->where('e.stateid = :stateid')
                ->setParameter('stateid', $stateId)
            ;
```

Or something like that. Is there are simple way I can do this? Ive heard talk of using form events but honestly, I don't even know where to start.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Ive read numerous blogs etc on the subject but I can't reproduce their results.

Comment: Why does it have to be AJAX free ?  the only way I can see to do it without AJAX is sending all the data to the client and filter the required results in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply topaz1008, I would really prefer not to add any extra complexity to the project if possible, but I think your probably right. Cheers again.